# Accessing functions defined in system.js from HTML

Tags: javascript, systemjs

When using system.js, what's the right way to access a function from the global scope? For example, suppose we have this HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="foo">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
</form>
<script src="/lib/system.js"></script>
<script>
SystemJS.import("/src/foo.js");
</script>
```

And we have this javascript:

```
function foo(form) { console.log("here"); }
```

How do you get SystemJS to export `foo` in such a way that it can be called when the form is submitted?

Comment: Off the top of my head make sure the paths to system.js and foo.js are correct. Other than that you should be able to import and use the functions the way you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
<form onsubmit="return foo(this);">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
</form>
<script src="/lib/system.js"></script>
<script>
SystemJS.import("/src/foo.js");
</script>
```

And `foo` should return `true` or `false` in order to signal whether the form should be submitted by the `action` attribute. As this is missing, I assume `false` is right here.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used system.js but a brief look at their docs told me that the `import` call returns a promise which resolves with the namespace of the module being imported. Perhaps you can try something like:

```html
<form onsubmit="foo">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
</form>
<script src="/lib/system.js"></script>
<script>
SystemJS.import("/src/foo.js")
.then(function(foo){
  window.foo = foo;
});
</script>
```

Or, if you want to avoid polluting the global namespace:

```html
<form id="foo-form">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
</form>
<script src="/lib/system.js"></script>
<script>
SystemJS.import("/src/foo.js")
  .then(function(foo){
    document.getElementById('foo-form')
            .addEventListener('submit', function(ev){
                foo(...arguments);
                ev.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
  });
</script>
```